# VUE with JSONP, always shows SyntaxError: Unexpected token?

Tags: vue.js, jsonp

I rebuild my code from Angular to Vue. and I meet a strange problem.

for Angular version, it is running correct:

```
var hq_str_fx_susdcad;
function getRate(){
    $http.jsonp("http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=fx_susdcad");
    if(hq_str_fx_susdcad != undefined){
        console.log(hq_str_fx_susdcad);
    }
    $interval(getRate,3000,1);
 }
```

it will get data from http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=fx_susdcad each 3 seconds, and show the value if it is not undefined.

the results is :

```
var hq_str_fx_susdcad="12:42:35,1.2601,1.26018,1.2589,23.7,1.25876,1.26051,1.25814,1.2601,美元兑加拿大元即期汇率,0.1,0.0012,0.001883,Dukascopy Bank,1.37937,1.25404,-+--++-+,2017-07-21";
```

for Vue version.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el:'.container',
  data:{
      hq_str_fx_susdcad:'';
  },
  methods: {
      autoReload: function(){
          console.log("get rate")
          this.$http.jsonp('http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=fx_susdcad',
            function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
          );
      }

  },
  mounted(){
      this.autoReload();
}

})
```

what ever I setup. it always shows that:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

Please kindly help to check how to make it works. BTW, I cannot change any part of server http://hq.sinajs.cn/ .
Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `this.$http` it looks like you are using vue-resource.

Vue-resource is a promise based API. The syntax for the request should be

```
this.$http.jsonp('http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=fx_susdcad')
    .then((data) => { 
        console.log(data) 
    } );
```

And in the data property remove the `;` as data is object
So it should be

```
data:{
     hq_str_fx_susdcad:''
     },
```

Comment: thanks! I adjust the code . finally I found that when I get the date within $http.jsonp, the url return the wrong javascript code: var hq_str_fx_susdcad?callback=_jsonpshav2="";  it should be var hq_str_fx_susdcad=xxxxxx.  I'll keep study that.

Comment: @shawn happy to help :)